How to get date time format in spring boot mongodb
This code is not working to get date as string format in dto class, please let me know the fix.
I've used this @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "dd-MM-yyyy") but nothing seems working. please suggest.
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude.Include;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation.JsonDeserialize;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation.JsonSerialize;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jsr310.deser.LocalDateTimeDeserializer;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jsr310.ser.LocalDateTimeSerializer;
import org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat;

import java.time.LocalDateTime;

@JsonInclude(value = Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public interface TransactionDTO {

    String getId();
    Long getTicketOrderId();
    Long getUserId();
    
    @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE_TIME)
    @JsonSerialize(using = LocalDateTimeSerializer.class)
    @JsonDeserialize(using = LocalDateTimeDeserializer.class)
    LocalDateTime getCreatedDate();

}


MongoDB support "Date" type. Library jackson isn't used by mongodb, you must implement a Converter for read and write dates into mongodb
public class LocalDateTimeReadConverter implements Converter<Date, LocalDateTime> {
@Override
public LocalDateTime convert(Date date) { return LocalDateTime.ofInstant(date.toInstant(), ZoneOffset.UTC); }
}
public class LocalDateTimeWriteConverter implements Converter<LocalDateTime, Date> {
@Override
public Date convert(LocalDateTime localDateTime) { return Date.from(localDateTime.toInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC)); }
}

Try custom custom Serializer and Deserializer:
@JsonSerialize(using = CustomLocalDateTimeSerializer.class)
@JsonDeserialize(using = CustomLocalDateTimeDeserializer.class)
LocalDateTime getCreatedDate();

The implementation:
Serializer:
public class CustomLocalDateTimeSerializer extends 
    StdSerializer<LocalDateTime> {
        private static final DateTimeFormatter formatter = 
        DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-yyyy");   
  


    public CustomLocalDateTimeSerializer() {
        super(LocalDateTime.class);
    }

    @Override
    public void serialize(LocalDateTime value, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException {
        gen.writeString(formatter.format(value));   

    }
}

Deserializer:
public class CustomLocalDateTimeDeserializer extends StdDeserializer<LocalDateTime> {

    private static final DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-yyyy"); 
  
    public CustomLocalDateTimeDeserializer() {
        super(LocalDateTime.class);
    }

    @Override
    public LocalDateTime deserialize(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException {
        return LocalDateTime.parse(p.getText(), formatter);
    }
}

